# how to get files inside the folder to be zip Archive

Tags: zend-framework

```
  $source="/Filelist/"
 $filter = new Zend_Filter_Compress(
                        array(
                        'adapter' => 'Zip',
                        'options' => array(
                                                        'archive' => test.zip
                                                      )
                                )                     
                    );
       $result = $filter->filter($source);
```

the function work fine ,the problem is that i want to get the file list inside the test.zip .but now i am getting the folder Filelist inside the archive.

it seems to because of line $content  = str_replace(array('/', '\'), DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR, realpath($content)); and the realpath is removing '/'
Any solution ????????????????

Answer (score 0):

Looking at the code, I don't see a way of doing that. Zend_Filter_Compress_Zip checks if it is a dir, and if it is, calls:

```
$zip->addEmptyDir(substr($local, 0, -1));
```